# problemas con javascript habilitar deshabilitar link de una tabla

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hola a todos agradecería me puedan ayudar.

Estoy realizando un proyecto en `PHP` y lo que deseo es que cada vez que traigo un resultado de la base de datos, me deshabilite un link `<a href=www.google.com>`. Quiero que a través de `Javascript` o `Jquery` me anule ese link de una tabla que dice editar.

Estoy intentando hacerlo pero no logro solucionar ese problema.

Líneas abajo pongo mi script.

```
<?php 
    if ($row['aprob_jt']=='a') {
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
      echo 'const a=document.querySelector("a");
          function deshabilitar() {
              a.href="#";
          }';
      echo '</script>';
    }
?>

<td>
    <a href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
        <center>
            <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
        </center>
    </a>
</td>
```

Comment: El hecho de deshabilitar (mostar) un link, no significa que no podrá usarse, si conoces el link solo hay que cambiarle la variable id y con eso ingresas igual, yo te recomendaría una variable al inicio de dicho link que validase si es susceptible de ser editado y esa variable podrías setearla desde la página de origen digamos que a través de una variable de sesión y luego al cargar dicho link cambiarle el estado a dicha variable a FALSE nuevamente.

Answer (score 0):

Los enlaces no se pueden deshabilitar porque no admiten el atributo `disabled`; aparte, ese código no va a funcionar porque estás declarando el script antes de crear el elemento en HTML y no lo va a encontrar, de hecho, solo tomaría el primer enlace que aparezca en todo el documento.

Otro posible problema es que estés mostrando todo en un ciclo y aparezca varias veces el script, entonces vas a obtener un error por declarar una variable más de una vez con `const a=document.querySelector(a);`

Ya que estás generando el contenido desde PHP, entonces realiza los cambios ahí mismo:

```
<td>
    <?php
        if($row['aprob_jt']=='a') {
            // No hay enlace, puedes mostrar cualquier otra cosa
            echo 'X'; 
        } else {
            // Sí hay enlace
    ?>
        <a href="?action=editar&id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
            <center>
                <i class="fas fa-edit"></i>
            </center>
        </a>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</td>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta amigo, me sirvio de mucho.

Comment: La respuesta que ha sido válida para tu pregunta debería ser aceptada, para que la comunidad lo sepa y la pregunta no quede eternamente pendiente de respuesta.  Pulsa en este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) para aprender a aceptar las respuestas, gracias.